# Flask Form Doesn't Update SQL Database

Tags: sql, flask

I am learning flask and am building a flask app which is a basic social blogging platform. There are a couple of issues which have been bugging me but I figure it would be best to split theses separate issues into separate questions. One issue occurs when a user is logged in and the blog post form doesn't create the blog posts/doesn't update the database. Another similar issue occurs on the update user form so I'm guessing the issue lies in my implementation of flask-sql but have not been able to work out where the bug comes from. This is also my first question asked so I put what I thought were the relevant files; if anything else is needed I can update the post. Also, if anyone knows an effective way to paste code automatically indented 4 spaces in for formatting on stack overflow would be appreciated--I had to do it manually. Thank you.

account.html

```
<div class='jumbotron'>
    <div align='center'>
        <h1>Welcome to the page for {{current_user.username}}</h1>
        <img align='center' src="{{url_for('static',filename='profile_pics/'+current_user.profile_image)}}">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{form.hidden_tag()}}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form.username.label(class="form-group")}}
            {{form.username(class='form-control')}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form.email.label(class="form-group")}}
            {{form.email(class='form-control')}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form.picture.label(class="form-group")}}
            {{form.picture(class="form-control-file")}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form.submit(class="btn btn-primary")}}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

forms.py (UpdateUserForm only)

```
class UpdateUserForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(),Email()])
    username = StringField('UserName',validators=[DataRequired()])
    picture = FileField('Update Profile Picture', validators[FileAllowed(['jpg','png'])])
    submit = SubmitField('Update')

    def check_email(self, field):
        if User.query.filterby(email=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('Your email has been registered already!')

    def check_username(self, field):
        if User.query.filterby(username=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('Your username has been registered already!')
```

views.py (account update view only)

```
@users.route("/account",methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def account():
    form = UpdateUserForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.picture.data:
            username = current_user.username
            pic = add_profile_pic(form.picture.data,username)
            current_user.profile_image = pic

        current_user.username = form.username.data
        current_user.email = form.email.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('User Account Updated!')
        return redirect(url_for('users.account'))

    elif request.method=="GET":
        form.username.data = current_user.username
        form.email.data = current_user.email

    profile_image = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/'+current_user.profile_image)
    return render_template('account.html',profile_image=profile_image,form=form)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This question doesn't really seem to be related to the SQL _language_,)

Comment: flask-sqlalchemy which I believe uses sqlite. I included the SQL language due to the interaction, in the future, would it be better to leave addressing the language out?